# How to remove newline with Starship?

Tags: newline, kitty, starship

I want to have a very minimalistic prompt in my `kitty terminal emulator (kitty 0.28.1 created by Kovid Goyal)`. I am having trouble to remove a `newline` in my [starship](https://starship.rs/) prompt.

Here a picture for illustrative purposes:

[image]

As you can see, by default this newline pops up when I write a new command or even when starting up the terminal.

Here is my *starship.toml*:

```
[character]
format = """
[ ─>](bold green) """

[username]
style_user = "green bold"
style_root = "black bold"
format = "[$user]($style)@[Kyurem]($style) [$path]($style)"

disabled = false
show_always = true

[directory]
format = "[$path]($style)[$read_only]($read_only_style) "
style = "bold #f57800"

[git_status]
disabled = true
```

How can I change this to remove the empty line? I tried `add_newline = false`, but that didn't seem to work because the key is not recognized:

> [WARN] - (starship::config): Error in 'Username' at 'add_newline':
> Unknown key

I'm using `GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`. I appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: The `add_newline = false` seems ok (see: https://starship.rs/config/#prompt:~:text=starship%20(in%20milliseconds).-,add_newline,-true)   But did you put it in the correct place in your `starship.toml` file ?  Can you try to add it before  the line `[character]` ?

Comment: @Luuk Yes that did indeed do the trick. Thanks :)